# I wanna play recording again in existing file

Tags: android, playback, voice-recording

I am a newbie.
I'm developing an android (4.2) app to record some audio.

The code seems to run fine the first time, and it even saves the files on the SD Card.
But, if I try to record again, my app crashes.

This is my code:

```
StringVoiceFile = PathImagePage + "/"+book_id+"-"+pagenumber+".mp3";
myAudioRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
myAudioRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
myAudioRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
myAudioRecorder.setOutputFile(StringVoiceFile);
```

this is my function

```
public void start(){

    String PathImagePage = AppDirectory+"/content/"+userid+"/books/"+book_id+"/";
    StringVoiceFile = PathImagePage + "/"+book_id+"-"+pagenumber+".mp3";
    File VoiceFile = new File(PathImagePage, +"-"+pagenumber+".mp3");
    MediaPlayer m = new MediaPlayer();

    if (VoiceFile.exists()){    

        try {

            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            m.setDataSource(StringVoiceFile);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            myAudioRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            Log.e(TAG, "start() failed = " + e );
        }
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        time.setEnabled(true);
        time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        time.setText(formatTime(m.getDuration()));
        play.setEnabled(false);
        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        startRecordingTimer(now);
        Alert.ToastAlert(FlipActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.record_start_again));
    } else {

        try {

            myAudioRecorder.prepare();
            myAudioRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

            Alert.ToastAlert(FlipActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.record_nostart));
        } catch (IOException e) {

            Alert.ToastAlert(FlipActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.record_nostart));
        }
        stop.setEnabled(true);
        stop.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        time.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        time.setText(formatTime(m.getDuration()));
        play.setEnabled(false);
        play.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        startRecordingTimer(now);

        Alert.ToastAlert(FlipActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.record_start));
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: If your app is crashing, it would be extremely helpful if you attach the crash log so we know what actually happened, instead of having to examine all of your code without any hint on what's going to fail.

Comment: https://github.com/Hariharan-Gandhi/RecordingAudioSamples .Wav file recorder

Comment: _`".mp3"`_ <-- You realize that what you're actually creating isn't an MP3 file, but a 3GPP file with AMR-NB-encoded data, right?

Comment: @Micheal for first time play no problem. still playing sound normal